# Angular returns blank response.data from json api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

ng-repeat returns blank, I am new to Angular. I checked for errors but found none. I really do not know what is wrong here.

```js
(function() {

  var app = angular.module("testApp", []);

  app.controller("MainController", function($scope, $http) {
   $scope.search = function(username) {
  $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username)
    .then(onUserComplete, onError);

  $http.get($scope.user.repos)
    .then(onRepos, onReposError);
};

var onUserComplete = function(response) {
  $scope.user = response.data;
};

var onRepos = function(response) {
  $scope.repos = reponse.data;
};
  });

}());
```

below is the HTML, where I wanted to display the repository of particular users on GitHub:

```html
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Stars</th>
       <th>Language</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="repo in repos">
        <td>{{repo.name}}</td>
        <td>{{repo.stargazers_count }}</td>
        <td>{{repo.language}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thank you @rrd I did not know that they were different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the HTTP calls you're doing are asynchronous, so when you execute the second one, you don't have the user yet. You must concatenate the promises. And if you're not going to use the user anywhere, only for the second call, then you could simplify your code:

```
$http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username)
     .then(function(response) {
         return $http.get(response.data.repos_url);
     })
     .then(function(response) {
         $scope.repos = reponse.data;
     }, 
     onError);
```

The first *then* is executed when the first *get* is successful, so I call the second *get*. Then the second *then* is executed when the second HTTP call is successful. This way we have concatenated both promises.

I've written a complete example at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eyanez/1syz7p5r/39/).

But I've copied here the complete code, so it could be useful for others:

**AngularJS**

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

myModule.controller('myController', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var $ctrl = this;
    $ctrl.username = null;
    $ctrl.repos = null;


    $ctrl.getRepositoryData = function () {   
        $ctrl.repos = null;
        $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/' + $ctrl.username)
             .then(function(response) {
                 return $http.get(response.data.repos_url);
             })
             .then(function(response) {
                 $ctrl.repos = response.data;
             }, 
             function (error) {
                 console.log('Error happened:', error);
             });
    };
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myModule">
    <div ng-controller="myController as ctrl">
        <div>
            <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.username"/>
            <button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.getRepositoryData()">
                Get Repos
            </button>
            <p>User repositories: {{ctrl.repos}}</p>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am sorry I have no idea about what it means to concatenate promises. An example will be much appreciated

Comment: My answer is an example of that

Comment: Still can't get it to work @Eduardo, thank you for you help. Perhaps more reading will help me understand your contributions better. thanks

Comment: @DunkuMajor I've updated my answer with a complete functional example. Run it on JSFiddle and review the code, so you can see how it works. Of course, read how promises work, because $http.get return a promise.

Comment: This is very clear now. I have followed the reasoning and it is understandable. Many thanks @Eduardo.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call 
  $http.get($scope.user.repos)
    .then(onRepos, onReposError); inside onUserComplete function. Angular http module methods are async . So after making a get or post call ,angular will forget about it and continue with the execution.